# What does the "keleven" digit look like?

Tags: the-office

In the Finale episode of The Office, we learn that one reason Kevin was fired, was for using his made-up number "kelevin" to correct accounting errors.  His replacement is seen asking Oscar about this "strange symbol."  Do we have any way of knowing what this symbol looks like?

Comment: I think that any answer would have to be speculative at best whihc makes this not a good question

Comment: @APaleShadow: No, that would make a bad answer. The question could very well be answered authoritatively, if the "kelevin" digit has ever been written, and if the producers or actors from the show ever disclose this information.

Comment: We may well one day be fortunate enough to see what the Keleven looks like, when the original format recording is hopefully released. It all depends on the producers of the show. We have the technology and the storage capacity to make it happen. The original film recording almost definitely includes the Keleven as seen at minute 7 second 14 in the final episode 'Finale' (s09e23) of The Office. [when Dakota is questioning Oscar]

Comment: Kevin was referring to a 'plug' it isn't a symbol. For example if you are trying to reconcile something and you are off by 200. You would just create a plug (keleven) equal to 200 to have the account balance. Think of it as an offset.

Comment: You've apparently never watched that episode, or read the existing answer or even the question. They clearly refer to it as a written symbol.  "Dakota: Hi. I keep seeing this symbol in the accounts from last year. It’s..it’s all over the place. I don’t know what it means."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the keleven, as you say, was used by Kevin to balance the books:

> Oscar: [on the phone] Years ago, the senator promised a left turn lane
> by the Arby’s. So I wanna know where in the name of horsey sauce is
> it? Well, yeah, you…hold on.
>
> Dakota: Hi. I keep seeing this symbol in
> the accounts from last year. It’s..it’s all over the place. I don’t
> know what it means.
>
> Oscar: That’s the reason Kevin got fired. It’s
> his magic number. He used to use it to balance his accounts. He used
> to call it a Keleven. He told Dwight, [imitating Kevin] “A mistake
> plus Keleven gets you home by seven.” He was home by 4:45 that day.

Aside from these words and despite extensive googling, there is absolutely no reference anywhere to what the symbol might actually *look like*. I even went through a combination of different searches on google images and instagram, but came up empty handed.

Therefore, I'm going to say **no**, we have no way of knowing what the symbol looks like as the producers of the show have never attempted to release it (and have likely never even created it).

Comment: Ditto. I searched extensively as well.